# iframe works on a page, but not a single, why?

Tags: html

I am trying to load a vimeo video into a single page, but it is telling me:

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

but on other pages the same iframe, copied and pasted into a page template, works fine.

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/4426465" width="400" height="230" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: When you say "single page", you mean when you view a blog post page? And when you say "page template", you mean when you view a blog "page", like About Us?

Comment: Yes and yes. single = single.php, page = page.php

Comment: Please add a link that is demonstrating the problem otherwise this is too hard to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is message given by Vimeo? In that case it's probably better to ask them.

I know that WP likes to strip out iframes completely, but if it did get to display nothing more WP can break.

Comment: WP strips out iFrames? I have plenty of them

Comment: Not by default, but it's common if you switch between HTML and visual editor for example.

Comment: this code is going straight into the theme files.

Comment: In that case it's extremely unlikely for WP to do anything to it.

Comment: It's not. Definitely. The iframe is launching, it's just not rendering.

Comment: Are there any scripts included on single.php that aren't on page? Look in header.php and footer.php see if there are any conditional statements loading scripts on single. if( is_single(); )  etc.

Answer (score 0):

> It's not. Definitely. The iframe is
>   launching, it's just not rendering

Then it's hardly a WP question...
Time to call Vimeo support.